# Having trouble rotating model in three.js

Tags: three.js

Having trouble to rotate the 3d model on three.js, I was thinking it can be a scope problem. Declared model as a variable outside the loader but still does not work

```
// model

const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("/draco/");
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);


let model;
gltfLoader.load("/models/a_greek_general.glb", (gltf) => {
  gltf.scene.traverse((node) => {
    if (!node.isMesh) return;
    // material
    node.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: neon });
    model = gltf.scene;
  });

  scene.add(model);
});
```

tried to rotate the model with the elapsedTime

```
/**
 * Animate
 */
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
let previousTime = 0;

const tick = () => {
  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
  const deltaTime = elapsedTime - previousTime;
  previousTime = elapsedTime;
  // Update controls
  model.rotation.y = 0.4 * elapsedTime;

  controls.update();
  // Render
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // Call tick again on the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

tick();
```